# MYSQL Trigger works if I use 'after update' but not 'after insert'?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I've written a trigger to insert a row into table b after an operation on table a.
For some reason, it has no effect if I add this trigger 'after insert' and then insert a row.  However, it does work if I add the trigger as 'after update', and update the row.

Here's the trigger code.  When I replace 'AFTER UPDATE' with 'AFTER INSERT', and do an insert, then nothing happens when i insert a new row.  I get no errors when creating the trigger, and I am not trying to update the same table the trigger is being set upon.
Any help is appreciated!
thanks,
Jen

```
drop trigger if exists insertUndecided;  
DELIMITER //  
CREATE TRIGGER insertUndecided  
     AFTER UPDATE ON jiraissue
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
        insert into nodeassociation (SOURCE_NODE_ID, SOURCE_NODE_ENTITY, SINK_NODE_ID, SINK_NODE_ENTITY, ASSOCIATION_TYPE, SEQUENCE)
   select
      NEW.id as SOURCE_NODE_ID,
      'Issue' as SOURCE_NODE_ENTITY,
      (select pv.id from projectversion pv
         where pv.vname='undecided'
         and pv.project=NEW.project ) as SINK_NODE_ID,
      'Version' as SINK_NODE_ENTITY,
      'IssueFixVersion' as ASSOCIATION_TYPE,
      NULL as SEQUENCE

   from dual  where exists
      (select pkey from jiraissue
         where id=NEW.id and id not in
            (select distinct source_node_id from nodeassociation
               where source_node_entity='Issue' and SINK_NODE_ENTITY='Version'
               and ASSOCIATION_TYPE='IssueFixVersion') );

 END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: See this answer that seems to apply to your situation as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9097459/870122

Comment: Try to reproduce this behavior without trigger. Execute SELECT statement. Will it return any rows?

Comment: @perissf - thanks for your reply.  that issue is regarding "Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger."   While I am indeed reading the jiraissue table, I am not updating it.  And that does not  explain why it seems to work if i run it 'AFTER UPDATE', but not 'AFTER INSERT'?

Comment: @Devart - thanks for your reply.  Yes, I checked the select statements at the mysql prompt by replacing NEW.id and NEW.project with the newly added id and project.  they return expected results.

Comment: Has the jiraissue.id field the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute ? If so you may be running into something like NEW.id = 0 problem , but I have no specific arguments on this.

Comment: Do you have another `AFTER INSERT` trigger defined? Only one trigger per time is allowed

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL 5.5.20 with InnoDB tables i've reproduced your situation in a simplified test.
both, inserting using a result from the trigger table which is referring to the new row alreay and directly inserting using the NEW values worked fine

```
CREATE TABLE test1(a1 INT NOT NULL auto_increment, b1 INT, PRIMARY KEY (a1) );
CREATE TABLE test2(a1 INT, b1 INT);
CREATE TABLE test3(a1 INT, b1 INT);

DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER testAI AFTER INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test2 SET a1 = NEW.a1, b1 = NEW.b1;
    INSERT INTO test3 ( a1, b1 ) SELECT a1, b1 FROM test1 WHERE a1 = NEW.a1;
  END;
;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Fire the trigger

```
INSERT INTO test1 (b1) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
```

Directly inserted from NEW values

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test2;
+------+------+
| a1   | b1   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    3 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Inserted from SELECT result

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test3;
+------+------+
| a1   | b1   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    3 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.5.20    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So this works for both auto_increment and explicitly inserted values.
Your problem must be somewhere else